# Exporting graphic elements with transparent backgrounds in Fireworks

Tags: transparency, slice, fireworks

I've started using Fireworks to do prototypes, but now I need to code a prototype in HTML/CSS. I have all relevant image elements sliced, but the default behavior for Fireworks seems to be to export slides with any visible background elements embedded in the picture. E.g. When I export a logo I want the area around the logo to be transparent - I don't want the background behind the logo, which was located at a different layer.

Is it possible to export all elements with the transparency intact?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your logo to a new document and export it. Lay it on top of your header graphics using CSS or maybe table if you are going that way. The point is if you see the background colors around the logo in your slice view, there is no way of exporting it transparently. The purpose of slicing is to export what you see in the sliced rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no background in the image, either use the wand tool to delete the background or some other method and then make sure the images are exported as .png

Comment: All the individual images have transparent background already, as they where processed in Photoshop or created from scratch in Illustrator, but I have used some filters on some of the elements in fireworks and would like a one-step procedure to export all elements as they appear in fireworks. As it is now, I have a header-background and on an individual layer on top of this I have a logo. But when I export slices, the header-background is used as a background for the logo - I want the background around the logo to be transparent.